# Among A Group Of Friends

Tags: idioms, redundancy

I have a question about the usage of "among"

1. ***among*** friends
2. ***among*** *a group of* friends

Does "*among*" make "*group*" redundant?

Comment: Why do you think "among" would make "group" redundant?

Comment: I think you could be "among friends" with just a couple friends, but "a group of friends" suggests several friends at least, and, well, a grouping :-)

Comment: @snailplane So, adding or deleting "a group of" makes no difference?

Comment: @meatie I believe that is exactly what I didn't say.

Answer (score 1):

Among means "to be with". In the first example you used, the usage of among is correct. In the second example, however, using "among" does not make "group" redundant. The usage there is also correct. You are basically saying "With a group of friends."

Comment: To expand on this, "among" might make "group" redundant in terms of meaning, but not syntactically; as far as the English language is concerned, it's a perfectly valid combination. Myself I'd use "among friends", though.